# Need to add a whitelist to my .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, delete-file

So I have a .bat that deletes a certain extension, but I need to whitelist a few of them. I'm not having much luck.

```
xcopy "universe" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Backup\universe - %stamp%" /I
for %%i in ("universe\*.world") do if not "%%i"=="test.world" if not "%%i"=="test2.world" del /q "%%i"
exit
```

I made a some dummy files, but even test.world and test2.world is being deleted with everything else .world. Anyone have any idea?

If possible what I want is a simple text file that lets me add on file names onto it and let it whitelist it from there, because some of the .world names generated are pretty huge in names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution - the `/i` is needed to match upper and lower case and the `%%~nxi` matches the filename and extension.

```
for %%i in ("universe\*.world") do if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test.world" if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test2.world" del /q "%%i"
```

Comment: This works even better, especially if I forget the directories themselves. I thank both of ye.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to debug batch files ECHO is your friend.  Try this:

```
for %%i in ("universe\*.world") do echo %%i
```

This will print file names like "universe\test.world", which makes the problem clear.

You need to include the "universe\" in the names you are testing for, for example:

```
if not "%%i"=="universe\test.world"
```

You can make your code more readable by splitting it over multiple lines:

```
for %%i in (universe\*.world) do (
  if not "%%i"=="universe\test.world" (
  if not "%%i"=="universe\test2.world" (
    echo %%i
  ))
)
```

Note that on the line after the ECHO you need as many closing parentheses as you have IF statements.

Comment: Wait serious? I actually have to include the paths? Let me go try this. I have echo on already. It just never told me anything other than successful copies from xcopy.

Comment: This will fail if the case doesn't match.  It needs the `/i` switch in the if compare.